# In probability: is there a name for 1-x or x-1?

Tags: probability, terminology

I should frame this question in the context of dealing with probabilities:
I've read the wikipedia entry on the multiplicative inverse:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse
Where it clearly says that $x^{-1}$ is the inverse. But I feel like x-1 or 1-x has a name and I keep wanting to call it an inverse, when it seems like I shouldn't. Is there another name for this x-1 or 1-x phenomena?

Comment: $x^{-1}$ is a multiplicative inverse because $x \cdot x^{-1} = 1$.  $-x$ is an additive inverse because $x + (-x) = 0$.  What notable "inverse" property does $x-1$ or $1-x$ have? No, I am not aware of any such name.

Comment: Then again, this is vaguely reminiscent of a number's [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $x$ is a probability, then $1-x$ is the complementary probability.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementary_event

Answer (score 5):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no commonly used term for the relationship between $x$ and $1-x$.

Answer (score 3):

If you add $x-1$ and $1-x$, you get $$(1-x)+(x-1) = 0$$ Indeed, $(x-1)= -(1-x)$.

Each is the ***additive* inverse** of the other.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you mean is that $1-x$ is a sort of additive inverse of $x$ with respect to $1$. Moreover, the function is an involution as long as $x\in[0, 1]$, so applying this "inverse" twice gets you $x$ back. This operation is useful in probability, for instance, and I don't think it has a name, although if you called it the *complement* people wouldn't think you were crazy. If you're working with the reals or rationals modulo $1$, it's literally an additive inverse.

Answer (score 0):

If you're speaking of $x^{-1}$, then that's been answered in the comments.  If you're talking about $x - 1$ and $1 - x$, then the correct answer is they are each other's additive inverses. The additive inverse of $x$ is the number $-x$ such that $x + (-x) = 0$.  If we add $(x - 1) + (1 - x)$, we have $$(x - 1) + (1 - x) = x - 1 + 1 - x = x - x + 1 - 1 = 0$$Also notice that $(1-x) = -(x -1)$.